# How to run replicas on memory tmpfs on host in OpenEBS?

Tags: storage, openebs

Is their a way to run replicas on memory tmpfs on host. I got the problem (infinity restart)

```
time="2018-11-02T21:55:05Z" level=fatal msg="Error running start replica command: failed to find extents, error: invalid argument"
```

Is the service able to work on disks mounted in memory?

Answer (score 0):

Currently OpenEBS Jiva storage engine support only those file systems which supports extents mapping ext4,XFS etc... 
where as tmpfs does not support extents mapping hence it fails.